# Eagle 7 two finger scroll issue

Tags: eaglecad

I upgraded to Eagle 7 a couple of days ago the the scroll behaviour seems to have changed.
Using a two finger scroll on a mac trackpad I used to be able to pan around in Eagle 6 but using Eagle 7 this has now become zoom in and out.

Has anyone else experienced a change like this or does anyone know how to revert the behaviour?

Comment: I would think Eagle has a support page or forums which would be a more appropriate/faster way of getting your answer...

Comment: Perhaps, I followed previous similar questions which led me here and I didn't fancy registering on another site so I tried my luck.
I switched back to version 6 which has solved my problem for now.

Comment: How did you manage to get a version 7 license a couple of days ago?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem. Fortunately, it's an easy fix!

`Options > User Interface...`

1. Set `mouse wheel zoom` to `0`.
2. Turn `Legacy mouse wheel mode` off.

Enjoy!

Comment: you awesome !!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me on Eagle 7.6.0 on Macbook was typing `SET Interface.UseCtrlForPanning 1` into the command field (near the top of the window). The command key along with trackpad click-and-drag now pans. I found this solution [here](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/15012/l/scrolling-horizontal-vertical-using-mousetrackpad?displayFullThread=true).

My symptoms were the scrollbars were missing and nothing would pan the window. Two-finger pinch would zoom in and out, but no panning.